# What are some alternatives to making birdsmouth cuts in a rafter?

Tags: framing, structural, timber-framing

I'd like to avoid making a birdsmouth cut in my rafters since they are extending beyond the top plate in a cantilever, and I don't want to reduce the strength too much.

I've seen that there is VPA (Variable Pitch Connector) hardware available that can do this, but it has some limitations.

Someone told me that in smaller structures, (mine is 8' wide) you can just omit the birdsmouth cut altogether and it is fine. The top plate might get crushed slightly but not enough to worry about.

The other alternative that I've heard is cutting the studs to match the pitch of the roof so that the rafter sits fully flat on the top plate without any birdsmouth cut. I don't understand how this would work in terms of load forces... wouldn't the loads tend to slide off rather than being transferred down into the stud?

Are there other alternatives to a birdsmouth notch?

Comment: Tell us about the size of your rafters (lumber used, length) and the length of your overhang. You might be overthinking the strength question.

Comment: Well the overhang is cantilevered, and the cantilever rule is that it should be no more than 1/3 of the supported width. So if it's a 2x4 or a 2x20, that rule doesn't really change, right? But if your beam is actually 1/3 smaller at the point of support due to a birdsmouth, then you effectively have 1/3 extra weight on the cantilever. 

In other words, isn't this all relative? So the actual length/thickness, etc, doesn't matter.

Comment: That being said, it's a 2x8 overhanging 4'.

Comment: Well, you aren't losing 1/3 of a 2x8... your actual 7-1/4" is going to be ~5-3/4", which is pretty beefy, especially if your structure is only 8' wide. (I'm making assumptions that your pitch isn't outlandish.) So, I'd still do the birdsmouth.

Comment: It is a fairly steep pitch but also I'm fighting a design that is requiring notches to be taken out of the _other_ side of the rafter (facepalm).

Comment: A sketch might help...